Go template mapping issue with soap to json conversion
we use krakend and a plugin for soap to json conversion
{{if .promotionData}}
    "promotionData": {
        "identifier" : "{{.promotionData.identifier}}",
        "description": "{{.promotionData.description}}"
        {{if .promotionData.promotionBundleId}}
            ,"promotionBundleId": [
                {{- range $index, $id := .promotionData.promotionBundleId -}}
                {{- if $index}},{{end}}"{{ $id }}"{{- end -}}
            ]
        {{end}}
        {{if .promotionData.promotionServiceId}}
            ,"promotionServiceId": [
                {{- range $index, $ele := .promotionData.promotionServiceId -}}
                {{- if $index}},{{end}}"{{ $ele }}"{{- end -}}
            ]
        {{end}}
    }
{{else}}
    "promotionData" : []
{{end}}

expcted json response, some like
Here promotionBundleId and promotionServiceId can have empty, one value or multiple,if multiple then comma need to be there.
one of the expected output should be
"promotionData": {
"description": "promowithOnlyServiceDesc",
"identifier": "promowithOnlyServiceRule",
"promotionServiceId": ["2", "5", "3"],
"promotionBundleId": ["555"]
}
but facing error
but facing issue
2024-05-20 12:35:16             "promotionData": {
2024-05-20 12:35:16                 "identifier" : "promoRulewithOnlyOneBundle",
2024-05-20 12:35:16                 "description": "promowithOnlyOneBundledesc"
2024-05-20 12:35:16
2024-05-20 12:35:16                     ,"promotionBundleId": [
2024-05-20 12:35:16
2024-05-20 12:35:16
2024-05-20 12:35:16 2024/05/20 07:05:16 [Recovery] 2024/05/20 - 07:05:16 panic recovered:
2024-05-20 12:35:16 unexpected end of JSON input
2024-05-20 12:35:16 /build/apigw-plugins/modifierPlugin/modifierPlugin.go:396 (0x7fa68965a724)
2024-05-20 12:35:16 /build/apigw-plugins/modifierPlugin/modifierPlugin.go:227 (0x7fa689658b1e)
2024-05-20 12:35:16 /go/pkg/mod/github.com/luraproject/lura/v2@v2.6.3/proxy/plugin.go:179 (0x18537c1)
2024-05-20 12:35:16 /go/pkg/mod/github.com/luraproject/lura/v2@v2.6.3/proxy/plugin.go:104 (0x1853171)
i have tried multiple times with comma inside array manipulation

if it helps the soap response for that portion is something like this
<ns20:promotionData xsi:type="ns20:PromotionData">
ns20:identifierPromoRulewithOnlyOneBundle</ns20:identifier>
ns20:descriptionpromowithOnlyOneBundledesc</ns20:description>
ns20:promotionServiceId1</ns20:promotionServiceId>
ns20:promotionBundleId148</ns20:promotionBundleId>
ns20:promotionBundleId149</ns20:promotionBundleId>
</ns20:promotionData>
